# int() argument returning none

Tags: javascript, django-views

I am trying to make a wishlist functionality in my website. Not quite sure why product id returning none. My guess is that the js file could not access product id. In that case how can I solve the case?

views.py where the prod_is as returning none

```
@csrf_exempt
def addwishlist(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            prod_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
            product_check = Product.objects.get(id=prod_id)
            if(product_check):
                if(WishList.objects.filet(user=request.user, product_id=prod_id)):
                    return JsonResponse({'status':"Product already in wish list"})
                else:
                    WishList.objects.filet(user=request.user, product_id=prod_id)
                    return JsonResponse({'status':"Product added to wish list"})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'status':"No such product exists"})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status':"Login to continue"})
    return redirect('/')
```

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...


class WishList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

wishlist.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-wishlist').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var product_id=$(this).closest('.data_product').find('.prod_id').val();
        var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
        // Ajax
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"/add-wishlist",
            data:{
                'product_id': product_id,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: token
            },
            success: function(response){
                alertify.success(response.status)
            }
            });
        });
    });
```

wishlist.html:

```
{% extends 'customertemplates/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="container py-5 data_product"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4" style="float:left;">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="{{product.imageURL}}">
            <!--<h6><strong>{{product.product_name}}</strong></h6>
            <h4 style="display: inline-block;"><strong>${{product.discount_price}}</strong></h4>
            <br>-->
            <button style="width:375px" data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
            <br>
            {% if user.is_authenticated and user.is_customer %}
            <button style="width:375px" data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn add-wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart">Add to Wishlist</i></button>
            {% else %}
            <button style="width:375px" data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn"><a href="{% url 'customer_login' %}" class="ml-2"><i class="fa fa-heart">Add to Wishlist</i></a></button>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{product.id}}" class="prod_id">
            <h2 style="margin-top:10px;"><strong>{{product.product_name}}</strong></h2>
            <h7 style="color:white;">Brand: <strong>{{product.brand}}</strong></h7>
            <br>
            <h7 style="color:white;">In Stock: <strong>{{product.in_stock_total}}</strong></h7>
            <br>
            <h7 style="color:white;"> Price: <strong><strike style="color:red;">{{product.max_price}}$</strike></strong></h7>
            <h7 style="color:lightgreen;"><strong>{{product.discount_price}}$</strong></h7>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h7 style="color:white;">About Product: <p style="text-align:justify;">{{product.product_description}}</p></h7>
            <br>
            <h7 style="color:white;">Details: <p style="text-align:justify;">{{product.product_long_description}}</p></h7>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py:

```
path('wishlist/', customerviews.wishlist, name="wishlist"),
path('add-wishlist', customerviews.addwishlist, name="add-wishlist"),
```

The error I got:

```
 File "G:\website\projectwebsite\webiteapp\customerviews.py", line 168, in addwishlist   
 prod_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
 TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: What is the value of `var product_id=$(this).closest('.data_product').find('.prod_id').val()` before your Ajax call? I'd bet your issue is there, you are likely not grabbing the item you think

Comment: I am trying to get the product id by this argument but got it "undefined". I would be really grateful if you help me with the issue going on here and how I can fix it.

Comment: You aren't looping through a product list, which seems odd, but you have your `product` defined in context. You also have the `prod_id` stored in a hidden input, grab that. Your issue is simply passing the ID to your Ajax. My suggestion without just writing the code for you would be to `console.log()` your selection to ensure you are grabbing it correctly. This is a JS/HTML issue at this point, not a Django one.